# Electric Field at the Surface of a Hollow Infinite Cylinder Using Gauss Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

The electric field on the surface of a hollow infinite cylinder of radius r is given by $E=\frac{\sigma}{2 \pi r \epsilon_0}$, where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density.
But to find the electric field at some point on the surface, can't we just zoom in and get a flat sheet with a uniform perpendicular electric field of strength $E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct, the formula for the electric field is false (the dimensions are wrong). Using a cylinder as a Gauss's surface, Gauss's flux theorem gives you:
$$E ~2 \pi r L = \frac Q{\epsilon_0}$$ Where L is the length of the charge carrying cylinder, and r the radius of the Gauss's surface (cylinder).

$$Q= \sigma ~S= \sigma ~2 \pi R~L$$
Where R is the radius of the charge carrying cylinder.

It comes:  $r \geq R:~~~~E(r)= \frac{ \sigma~R }{  \epsilon _{0}~r } $

On the cylinder itself, you get: $E(R)= \frac{ \sigma }{  \epsilon _{0} } $